# force permalink slug for page vs post_type slug parent

Tags: permalinks, slug, post-type

I have setup permalink for post_type "directory" with this slug domain.com/directory/company-name

now when I try create page with domain.com/directory is detect as parent of post_type "directory" archive, is there any way for me to force permalink to detect "PAGE" slug? then I can put anything inside the page? thanks